# App getting crashed with react-native-maps package

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

My Android app getting crashed with below error message with react-native-maps package. Already tried with change `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'` to `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:**8.4.0**'` but didn't get it worked. RN version is 0.32 in windows environment.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError No static method
>   zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx' appears
>   in /data/app/com.ssssss-1/base.apk)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your error log, you're obfuscating your code. Assuming you're using proguard you can do the following:

You can turn off proguard by setting minifyEnabled to false in your gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Or you can add an the relative exceptions in the proguard-rules.pro. You can find the files for the react-native-maps library [here](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. Still getting the same. Also tried after with gradlew clean & npm cache clean.

Comment: App loaded after adding the following items at app/build.gradle. compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0"    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0' 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0' 
Now the app shows UPDATE button with message "this app won't run unless you update google play services"